# Python - generate pdf with multiple element on page

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf-generation

I need a Python script/method to combine different elements (tables, pyplot, text) into one single pdf page. Anyone familiar with a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

[Example on how my report page should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps4vV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can either do a full layout using report lab, *which is the most powerful and flexible but requires a lot of work,* or you can create the plot(s) as an image file(s) and put the tables and text, complete with reference to the image(s), into markdown and process with md2pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solutions suggested by Steve Barnes, you can also use matplotlib only. Matplotlib can generate plots, text ([`text`](http://matplotlib.org/users/index_text.html)) and [tables](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.table.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.table) and position them on a single figure, which can then be saved to pdf.

This can be a quick and easy solution, but will surely not give as nice results as [reportLab](http://www.reportlab.com).